Expression.Error - We cannot convert a value of type Function to type List
This M (Power Query) function gives this error "[Expression.Error] We cannot convert a value of type Function to type List." The objective is to output a table column being the difference between two source columns.
For Example:
•   1, 667
let
  Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [row = 1, first = "1234", second="567"],
        [row = 2, first = "9876", second="543"],
        [row = 3, first = "5437", second="890"],
        [row = 4, first = "2321", second="550"]
    }),
  Source2 = Table.FromColumns(
    {Source[#"row"], each Source[#"first"] - Source[#"second"]},{"row","diff"})
in
  Source2

Could anyone please point out the error? I am trying to subtract one existing column from another and put the result in a new column

The syntax for the Table.FromColumns function is incorrect. Are you just trying to do this?
let
  Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [row = 1, first = "1234", second="567"],
        [row = 2, first = "9876", second="543"],
        [row = 3, first = "5437", second="890"],
        [row = 4, first = "2321", second="550"]
    }),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"first", Int64.Type}, {"second", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [first]-[second]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"first", "second"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"


David - many thanks for your response

Your syntax is incorrect.
Perhaps this is what you want:
let
  Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [row = 1, first = "1234", second="567"],
        [row = 2, first = "9876", second="543"],
        [row = 3, first = "5437", second="890"],
        [row = 4, first = "2321", second="550"]}
    ),

Source2 = Table.FromColumns(
    {Source[#"row"]}
    & {List.Accumulate(
        {0..Table.RowCount(Source)-1},
        {},
        (s,c)=> s & {Number.From(Source[first]{c})-Number.From(Source[second]{c})})},
        type table[row=Int64.Type, diff=Int64.Type])
in
  Source2



Thanks Ron - really helpful response.
